# How to make docker cli use dockerhub v2 registry url

Tags: docker, dockerhub, spotify-docker-client

When I try to push an image like

```
docker push jikuma/dockercomposetest
```

it is resolved as

> docker.io/jikuma/dockercomposetest repository url.

I want to use v2 docker hub registry url. How can I do that. What should be my registry url. And how to make it default for docker client?

Here is docer version output.

```
Client: 
  Version:      17.06.0-ce     
  API version:  1.30  
  Go version:   go1.8.3    
  Git commit:   02c1d87
  Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
  OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
  Version:      17.06.0-ce
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.8.3
  Git commit:   02c1d87
  Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

Comment: What version of docker?

Comment: Client:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:30:30 2017
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.0-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.3
 Git commit:   02c1d87
 Built:        Fri Jun 23 21:51:55 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true

Comment: Are you not able to pull or push images?

Comment: There is a `--disable-legacy-registry               Disable contacting legacy registries (default true)` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/)

Comment: Here is my docker deamon configuration. {
  "registry-mirrors": [],
  "insecure-registries": [],
  "debug": true,
  "experimental": true,
  "disable-legacy-registry": true
}  . Still when i do docker login i get v1 registry url on config.json {
 "auths": {
  "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {}
 },
 "credsStore": "wincred"
}. I am using windows docker client and deamon.

Comment: You are using Docker toolbox or Docker for windows?

Comment: Docker for Windows. And now i have observed same behaviour in linux.

Comment: Seem like it. The behavior is consistent across all platforms "https://index.docker.io/v1/". The auth might be happen on this url and pull on a `v2` because the pulls happen on `registry-1.docker.io/v2`